# Firebase get more data with queryLimitedToLast

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I've a simple chat in swift and I retrieve 10 elements with queryLimitedToLast.

I want retrieve more element with a refresh function. How can increase the number of elements?

I've try to set the value in queryLimitedToLast with a variable but don't works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Queries are immutable; once you've created them, you cannot modify them.

So you'll have to create a new query, which starts at the end of the previous query.